# Dynamic Value in Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a object like as follows

```
var obj={
   userName:sessionStorage["userName"]
}
```

1st time if I try to access `obj.userName` i am getting undefined, because there is no value in it.

Now if I am getting undefined even after setting the value for it

```
sessionStorage["userName"]="name";
obj.userName;  //undefined
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`userName` takes the value of `sessionStorage["userName"]` at the time of its creation. Later changes to `sessionStorage["userName"]` will not be reflected in `userName`.

If you want to get `sessionStorage["userName"]` whenever you get value from `userName`, then you need to define a getter, like this

```
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
    userName: {
        get: function() {
            return sessionStorage["userName"];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well that was quick. +1

Comment: any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
sessionStorage["userName"]="name";
obj.userName = sessionStorage["userName"];
obj.userName;//name
```

Just changing the value of `sessionStorage` doesn't reflect the change to the object itself.

In order to change the object, you need to **actually** change the object.